# selecting unique pair form the list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

question is :
You are given a sorted array of positive integers and a number 'X'. Print out all pairs of numbers whose sum is equal to X. Print out only unique pairs and the pairs should be in ascending order.

```
input is: 1,2,3,4,6;5
output should be : 1,4;2,3
```

my code so far:

```
with open('/tmp/values.txt') as f:
    for numbers in f:
    num_list,sum_list = [  num.split(",")  for num in numbers.rstrip().split(";")]
sum_list = list(map(int,sum_list))
op1 = [(num_list[i],num_list[j]) for i in range(0,len(num_list)) for j in range(0,len(num_list)) if (eval(num_list[i])+eval(num_list[j]) == sum_list[0])]
print (op1)
```

output i got is:

```
[('1', '4'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '2'), ('4', '1')]
```

can anyone please help me with logic to select ('1','4') and ('2','3') from above list ?

Answer (score 1):

Since addition is commutative, you don't need to check twice:

```
with open('/tmp/values.txt') as f:
    for numbers in f:
        num_list, sum_list = [num.split(",") for num in numbers.rstrip().split(";")]

        sum_list = list(map(int, sum_list))
        op1 = [(num_list[i], num_list[j]) for i in range(len(num_list)) for j in range(i+1, len(num_list)) if (int(num_list[i]) + int(num_list[j]) == sum_list[0])]
        print(op1)
```

There's a `O(n)` solution (which I'll leave as an exercise for the reader.).

Answer (score 0):

there is a neat trick when doing two nested loops. if you dont want everything from the second list you do this:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    for j in range (i+1, 5):
        print str(i)+", "+str(j)
```

this results in:

```
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 3
2, 4
3, 4
```

This makes sure you dont keep looping over the same numbers again and again. this kind of thing tells the second loop not to start at the same place as the first loop, but to only start at a number it hasn't gotten to yet. (if you wanted to have the doubles like `0, 0`, `1, 1` ect. just take out the `+1` after `i`).

in your code you have two loops:

```
for i in range(0,len(num_list)) for j in range(0,len(num_list))
```

you could change the second loop to:

```
for j in range(i+1,len(num_list))
```